# sessionに入れられた配列の中身をすべて取得したい

Tags: jsp

サーブレット側

```
public class data{
private String id;
private String name;

public data(String id, String name){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
} //コンストラクタ


ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new data("1","aiueo"));
list.add(new data("2","kakikukeko"));
list.add(new data("3","sasisuseso"));
session.put("data",data);
```

```
//jsp側
<s:property value="session.data" />  //取得できない。

<s:property value="session.data" >
<s:property value="id" />
<s:property value="name" />
</s:property> //これもエラーが起きる
```

`<s:property >` タグを使い取得の仕方を教えてください

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/128005

Answer (score 1):

EL式で記述したいものと予想します。そうであれば、

```
<s:property value="${session.data}" />
```

あるいは、`session`を省略して単に

```
<s:property value="${data}" />
```

でどうでしょうか?

＃なお、この方法だと`ArrayList.toString()`と同じ結果になります。
  ですので、クラス`data`のメソッド`toString`をオーバーライドして、メンバ変数の値を文字列化する必要があります。